# Subset conditions in a Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, subset

I have this code:

```
# Sidebar to select the species
  sidebarPanel(
    radioButtons("species", "Species:",
                 list("Caretta caretta"="Cc", 
                      "Chelonia mydas"="Cm")),

# Sidebar to select the country (conditional of the species)

    radioButtons("country_type", "Choose:",
                 list("list", "coordinates")),

    conditionalPanel(
      condition="input.country_type=='list'",
      selectInput("country", "Country:",
                  choices=subset(NestingArea, Sp=='Cc')$Country)),
...
```

However, at `choices=subset(NestingArea, Sp=='Cc')$Country))` I would like that the `Sp` would be equal to the "species" chosen on the first `radioButton`, so that the list would change in consequence of the species. I have tried somethng like: `Sp==species` , `Sp=="species"` and `Sp==input.species` , but it doesn't work.

Any clue of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried input$species ?

Answer (score 0):

`subset` evaluates some of the arguments in unexpected environments which can, at times, be incompatible with how Shiny expects things to be run. The general advice is to avoid `subset` when working in Shiny apps for now.

So I'd replace

```
subset(NestingArea, Sp=='Cc')$Country
```

with

```
NestingArea[NestingArea$Sp=="Cc", "Country"]
```

Comment: You probably want to combine this, with Vincent's comment: so that you have `NestingArea$Sp==input$species` as the first thing in the brackets.